# ErrorHandler for Worksheet Selection Change

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I've been using the VBA code below to change the values in cells C6:C13 from "Show" to "Hide" at the click of a mouse.  It works great for it's intended purpose.  However, it will be necessary to hide/unhide column C from time to time, which is where I run into trouble.

Because it contains my KeyCells range, selecting column C generates a debug error.  I added an ErrorHandler to compensate--  but once it is triggered, the sub no longer functions until the sheet is closed/reopened.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

```
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With Target

  Dim KeyCells As Range
  Set KeyCells = Range("C6:C13")
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

     Select Case .Value
      Case "Show"
        .Value = "Hide"
      Case "Hide"
        .Value = "Show"
    End Select
  Range("B15").Select
  End If
  End With

  Application.EnableEvents = True

ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Comment: Move `Application.EnableEvents = True` after the `ErrorHandler:`. Otherwise, on an error, events aren't re-enabled. Also - replace `Range(Target.Address)` with `Target`.

Comment: @BigBen  Thanks for the quick fix!